# C# find string inside httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So i'm trying to find and grab a string from inside my httpwebresponse, I've already created a stream and can successfully read from the output to identify text inside the response, but now I'm trying to extract text from the response, for example:

Output contains,

```
    <script>
    var Site = 'home';

        var Home = {
            page: 24,
            name: 'Pokemon',
            Title: Pokemon chars
        };
     </script>
```

What I'm trying to do is extract only

```
 Pokemon
```

however this can change on various pages, so I can't just assume

```
name:
```

contains Pokemon

So what I need to do is trim name but keep the innertext, so what I've tried is something along the lines of

```
string str5 = "name: '";
foreach (string str6 in str3.Split(new char[] {'\n'}))  // str3 is = to the response given from the request which is now obviously a string its self.
{
   if (str6.StartsWith(str5))
   {
       str4 = str6.Replace(str5, "").Replace("',", "");
   }
}
```

Which should find the line containing " name: " then replace " name:" with nothing and the same for the end of that line leaving only the string

```
Pokemon
```

but it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: deserialize that json if its predictable

Comment: @Steve the variables are predictable but the content isn't

Comment: google c# deserialze JSON and you should be able to find what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options is to use Regular Expression, if you cannot deserialize your JSON.

```
string output = @"<script>
        var Site = 'home';

            var Home = {
                page: 24,
                name: 'Pokemon',
                Title: Pokemon chars
            };
         </script>";

         string regexPattern = @"name:\s'(.+?)',";
         Regex reg = new Regex(regexPattern);

         var match = reg.Match(output);

         if (match.Success)
         {
         Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
         }
```

Your are capturing everything between `name: '` and `',` using regular expression pattern.